# How to display results for a form in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently bringing a form into a div like this:

```
$('#m').load('http://example.com/converter/index.php #converty');
```

I need the results to display in the #m div, currently it takes me to the converter/index.php page, any help appreciated! The form that is loaded:

```
<form action="/converter/index.php" method="post" id="conversionForm" style="display: block;">
**do stuff**
</form>
```

FYI: the page with the script is at the root domain, while the converter is in the folder example.com/converter directory.

Comment: How is that a php question?

Comment: @E_p My bad, sorry.

Comment: You need to handle the submit of the form with javascript to interrupt the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Prevent the default behavior of the form submit by using the `.submit` method on the form element, then collect your form data by using `.serializeArray` and do what you need to do with it.

Here is an example.

```js
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var formData = $( this ).serializeArray();
  $.each(formData, function(i, item) {
    var $p = $("<p>");
    $p.text(item.name + ": " + item.value);
    $("#output").append($p);
  })
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
<form method="get" action="foo.php">
  <div><input type="text" name="a" value="1" id="a"></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="b" value="2" id="b"></div>
  <div><input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" id="c"></div>
  <div>
    <textarea name="d" rows="8" cols="40">4</textarea>
  </div>
  <div><select name="e">
    <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    </select></div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="f" value="8" id="f">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g">
  </div>
</form>
```